# Display Multiple ASP Items

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I need to display multiple ASP items. We have a back end tool where we can add multiple entries, but only the first two will display. I'm hoping there is just a minor code tweak that will allow additional pages to display. The code for the 2 pages that display the code are as follows:

```
<%
dim sql
sql = "select * from announcement_table where ann_status=1"
set rs = con.execute(sql)
%>
<%if not(rs.eof and rs.bof) then%>
<p><strong><%=rs("ann_title")%></strong> </p>
<p><%=rs("ann_text")%>
    <%else%>
  Currently there are no announcements.
  <%
end if
rs.close
set rs = nothing
%>
 </p>   
<hr size="1" noshade>
<%
dim sql_, sqlcount
sqlcount = "select count(*) from announcement_table"
set rscount = con.execute(sqlcount) 
sql_ = "select * from announcement_table where ann_status <> 1"
set rs_ = con.execute(sql_)
%>
<%if rscount(0)>1 then%>
<%if not(rs_.eof and rs_.bof) then%>
<a href="announcements_more.asp?ann_id=<%=rs_("ann_id")%>"><%=rs_("ann_title")%></a>         <br>
  <%else%>
  Currently there are no announcements.
    <%
end if
rs_.close
set rs_ = nothing
%>
<%end if
rscount.close
set rscount = nothing
%>
```

This is the 2nd page:

```
<%
dim sql_
sql_ = "select * from announcement_table where ann_id=" & intann_id
set rs_ = con.execute(sql_)
%>
<p><strong><%=rs_("ann_title")%></strong> </p>
<p><%=rs_("ann_text")%></p>

<%rs_.close
set rs_ = nothing
%>
```

Comment: Hello, sql injection vulnerability. The code in the 2nd page is practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: Can the page be hacked if I am the only one who has access to it? This is a back end tool that only I can access, so I was not too concerned about hacks, unless I am in error and it is somehow accessible otherwise? This tool has been this way for 15 years with no issues as far as hacks.

Answer (score 1):

in your second page,you need to loop through the recordset to show multiple values.

```
<%
    dim sql_
    sql_ = "select * from announcement_table where ann_id=" & intann_id
    set rs_ = con.execute(sql_)

    While Not rs_.EOF
    %>
    <p><strong><%=rs_("ann_title")%></strong> </p>
    <p><%=rs_("ann_text")%></p>

    <%
    rs_.Movenext
    Wend
    rs_.close
    set rs_ = nothing
    %>
```

and check this link too.[SQL Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)